# How to subscribe several lambda functions to the same SQS queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

What I want to achieve is to scale the number of consumers of a defined queue using lambda functions, instead of "self-hosted" subscribers.

For a given `event-queue` I want several consumers processing unique messages from this same queue, just like I would simply do with a cluster of processes, but I would like to use the cloud-hosted lambda functions. So far I just found how to subscribe with a single function, without scaling option.

Comment: Have you considered one Lambda function that fires off several others, either directly via Lambda or via a set of separate SQS queues?

Comment: Yes, but it would not be as simple to scale as it would be with just managing the number of active subscribers.

Answer (score 2):

I found this very helpful article from [cloudonaut.io](https://cloudonaut.io) (by Andreas Wittig), that exemplify one approach to multiple AWS Lambdas consumers:

[Integrate SQS and Lambda: serverless architecture for asynchronous workloads](https://cloudonaut.io/integrate-sqs-and-lambda-serverless-architecture-for-asynchronous-workloads/)

To scale Andreas' solution you can use [AWS CloudWatch Alarms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ConsoleAlarms.html) from your AWS SQS queue and tigger [AWS CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) (and/or [AWS Serverless Application Repository](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/serverlessrepo/)) to spin up more AWS Lambda consumers when needed.

Another approach is to use [Amazon MQ](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/).

If you use [Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS)](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/) or [AWS Kinesis](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/), the same message will trigger different lambdas and you'll probably get duplicated actions between your lambdas.

[update]

Now it is possible to use Amazon Simple Queue Service as a trigger for AWS Lambda:

More info here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-adds-amazon-simple-queue-service-to-supported-event-sources/